# "Error in formatNoSci(value) : argument "value" is missing, with no default" in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a very simple Shiny.

For some reason I get the errors
`Error in formatNoSci(value) : argument "value" is missing, with no default`
and
`Error in force(ui) : object 'ui' not found`.

I've googled these errors and can't find anything.

I can deduce that the `ui` isn't getting built for some reason, but I don't know why and I have no clue what `formatNoSci` does.

```
DF_custs <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,3), val=c(10, 20, 100, 200))

## app.R ##
server <- function(input, output) {

  get_cust <- reactive({
    cust <- DF_custs[which(DF_custs$ID == input$num), ]
    return(cust$val)})

  output$result <- renderText({ 
    ans <- get_cust()
    paste("You chose: ", ans)})
    }

ui <- fluidPage(
      numericInput(inputId="num", label="Pick an ID: "),
      fluidRow(
        column(1,
               fluidRow(
                 wellPanel(

      mainPanel(textOutput("result"))))))
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: in ` numericInput(inputId="num", label="Pick an ID: ")`, try defaulting the value to an ID that exists. If it defaults to null, I think it will try to run the reactive code in the server section and fail.

Comment: That most certainly fixed it! But why does it need a default value -- what if I'm piping in a csv and I actually don't know any values a priori? Seems sketch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per @Matt's comment, this is a problem with the initial state of the `numericInput` in `ui` being set to `NULL`, which triggers the reactive function in `server`. Some solutions would be to

1. Error handling in `server` to check that the input is not `NULL` before trying to retrieve `cust`, or
2. Initialising the `ID` to a default value which exists, or
3. Converting `numericInput` to a button style input where the reactive function is not calculated until the user presses "submit".

See also this question: [Shiny renderUI selectInput returned NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30378310/shiny-renderui-selectinput-returned-null)