# Forcing Reactive Chunk to be Evaluated

Tags: r, shiny

I have a complex Shiny app. I have a `selectize` output object, `selectTest`, the value of which is read by a reactive object, `isTestReady`. `isTestReady` evaluates whether certain conditions are satisfed by `selectTest`. `isTestReady` is then used in various chunks as a gate. I have set `selectTest` as `outputOptions(suspendWhenHidden = F, priority  999)` to ensure it gets up and running immediately.

On running, I notice the chunk for `selectTest` gets executed first. When `isTestReady` runs after this, it still reads the value of `selectTest` as NULL instead of whatever value that was assigned to `selectTest` in the first chunk. Shiny then goes through many of the other modules before returning to re-evaluate `isTestReady`. After the re-evaluation, the other chunks are called again and now they run fine.

Is that expected behaviour? If so, any ideas on how to make my scenario play the way I described it?

Example -

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


# Setup Shiny app UI components -------------------------------------------

ui <- dashboardPage(

   dashboardHeader(),
   ## Sidebar content
   dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
         uiOutput('someelement'),
         textOutput('temp2')
      )
   ),
   dashboardBody(  )

)


# Setup Shiny app back-end components -------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output) {

   output[['someelement']] = renderUI({
      selectizeInput(
         inputId = 'someelement',
         choices = letters,
         selected = letters[1],
         label = 'Custom Functions',
         multiple = F
      )
   })

   outputOptions(
      output,
      'someelement',
      suspendWhenHidden = F
   )

   temp = reactive({
      print('?')
      input[['someelement']]
   })

   observe({
      print('!')
      print(temp())
   })

   output[['temp2']] = renderText({
      print('!!')
      print(temp())
      '-'
   })

}

# Render Shiny app --------------------------------------------------------

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The logs output to the console for the above app look as follows -

```
[1] "!"
[1] "?"
NULL
[1] "!!"
NULL
[1] "!"
[1] "?"
[1] "a"
[1] "!!"
[1] "a"
```

Any way to avoid that NULL? In my app, there are a lot of chunks that look for `temp()`, all of which run before `temp()`.

Comment: Related but not a solution - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30378310/shiny-renderui-selectinput-returned-null?rq=1

Comment: You can bind `eventReactives` with other reactives too. Like so:`eventReactives{temp(), {}}`. Also you can have multiple of them in there too

Comment: @PorkChop, I'm creating new output objects based on `temp()` so `eventReactive` isn't an option. Unless I do the messy `local`, etc. business.

Answer (score 0):

try using observe() and reactiveValues(), see the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436713). reactive() is lazy.

I edited your question so variable names in your text match you code. But I might have miss you point. Something like this?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


# Setup Shiny app UI components -------------------------------------------

ui <- dashboardPage(

  dashboardHeader(),
  ## Sidebar content
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      uiOutput('ui_selectTest') 
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(  )

)


# Setup Shiny app back-end components -------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output) { 

  rv<- reactiveValues()

  output$ui_selectTest = renderUI({
    selectizeInput(
      inputId = 'selectTest',
      choices = letters,
      selected = letters[1],
      label = 'Custom Functions',
      multiple = F
    )
  })

  observe(
    if(!is.null(input$selectTest)) { 
      #check select test
      rv$testReady <- input$selectTest
    }
  )

  observeEvent(rv$testReady,{
    print(  rv$testReady  )
  })
} 

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks. This suggestion is similar to the link I put in my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `validate`in each of your reactive chunks to check for all needed inputs and conditions. Your server function would then look something like this

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  output[['someelement']] = renderUI({
    selectizeInput(
      inputId = 'someelement',
      choices = letters,
      selected = letters[1],
      label = 'Custom Functions',
      multiple = F
    )
  })

  outputOptions(
    output,
    'someelement',
    suspendWhenHidden = F
  )

  temp = reactive({
    #check if someelement is a valid input
    validate(need(input[['someelement']] %in% letters, "need input")) 
    print('?')
    input[['someelement']]
  })

  observe({
    #check if tmp() has already been evaluated
    validate(need(temp(), "need tmp"))  
    print('!')
    print(temp())
  })

  output[['temp2']] = renderText({
    validate(need(temp(), "need tmp"))
    print('!!')
    print(temp())
    '-'
  })

}
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks promising. I'll check this on my app once (which might take me a day or two). I'll check mark the answer if it work.

Comment: I have a feeling this basically blocks the execution of the rest of the observe chunk because of temp's NULL value, and doesn't actually force the evaluation of temp.