# shiny selectInput does not react to deselect all elements

Tags: r, shiny

How to observe of deselecte all elements of `selectInput` in `shiny`?

for example

```
library(shiny)

ui=shinyUI(fluidPage(
  selectInput("select","",choices = c(1,2),multiple = T)
  ))

server=function(input, output,session) {
  observeEvent(input$select,{
    print(input$select)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

actions :

1) select 1

2) select 2

3) deselect 2

4) deselect 1

console log:

```
[1] "1"
[1] "1" "2"
[1] "1"
```

So there is no print when all deselected.

It is bug or i do something in wrong way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

observeEvent does not react to NULL. This is usefull in most cases, See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30378310) , the answer by @daattali.

You have two options, 1) use observe

```
library(shiny)

ui=shinyUI(fluidPage(
  selectInput("select","",choices = c(1,2),multiple = T)
  ))

server=function(input, output,session) {
  observe({
    print(input$select)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

2) set the ignoreNULL parameter to FALSE in observeEvent(), as suggested by @WeihuangWong

```
library(shiny)

ui=shinyUI(fluidPage(
  selectInput("select","",choices = c(1,2),multiple = T)
))

server=function(input, output,session) {
  observeEvent(input$select,{
    print(input$select)
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE) 
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: To add to the answer, you can also set the `ignoreNULL` parameter to `FALSE` to get the same behavior, i.e. `observeEvent(input$select,{print(input$select)}, ignoreNULL = FALSE)`.

Comment: @WeihuangWong It better than simply observe ( my mind) because observe call multyple times in my real case , thanks

Comment: Good point @WeihuangWong. Will edit the answer to include your point.